# VS 2008/2010 Installation problem

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, visual-studio

*This comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5514689/684646), but since people has told me I should post this here, and not in StackOverflow, here I am...*

Here's the thing:

When I get to the license terms the installation window "dies". I mean, looks like it's working a lot (renderizing the objects of the window, showing the loading cursor), and it would be normal if my pc were old, but I do not.

The strangest part is when I check the task manager. It shows an invisible line at 25% of cpu resource usage for the installation program, and even when the proc has nothing else to do, this percentage doesn't grow. What keeps on growing is the RAM usage.

I've tried to give Realtime priority to the process without generating any changes to it (still @25%).

What bothers me is that my atom netbook can install both VSs without any further problems, but my far more efficient PC can't.

My PC Specs

- Processor: Intel Core i5 x64
- OS: Win7 Professional x64
- RAM: 6gb

Is the OS the problem? Is it Visual Studio?

Thanks for your answers, even workarounds will be well received at this instance.

*To add to this I have to say that vs2005 is actually installed in the troubled PC and works perfectly.*

Comment: This may seem obvious, but have you rebooted your machine before installing VS?

Comment: Before? yes I did. I've tried even installing VS even running in failsafe mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you should have a look at the log files.
I believe they are placed under the **%temp%** folder. They might point you in the right direction. There is also a log collection tool that you can use: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e0da314f-6216-4a18-bc6b-7d29cf83af20&displaylang=en)

Comment: That link is for Visual Studio 2002 and Visual Studio 2003 (¬.¬) There is even a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904732) to go to "troubleshoot VS2005".. although newer is also useless, because I said that 2005 had been installed. At least look at what you are replying. D=   Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Sorry, answered that one too quickly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home... but I'm not sure if the processor usage % would be changing the log.